# passing json to cfhttpparam

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 2016 and here is what i am doing:

```
<cfhttp method="put" url="https://www.colorfulapi.com/testpage/#arguments.Name#" username="#request.APIusername#" password="#request.APIToken#" result="results">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfif isStruct(arguments.structform) AND !StructIsEmpty(arguments.structform)>
    <CFHTTPPARAM VALUE="'#serializeJSON(stFields)#'" TYPE="body">
    </cfif>
  </cfhttp>
```

st are like this: if i dump them

```
'{"ONE":{"GROUP":"my group"}}'
```

if it goes to the cfhttpparam using `serializeJSON` it shows me as:

```
"error":"JSON error: 822: unexpected token at ''{\"ONE\":{\"GROUP\":\"my  group\"}}''"}
```

i tried the same code in POSTman, but in `POSTman` for `JSOn` sending i had to use the body as raw and choose content as `application/json` and it worked there

This is how i am generating my stFields

```
<cfset stFields = StructNew()>
  <cfset stFields.one = arguments.structform>
  <cfdump var="'#serializeJSON(stFields)#'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes:

```
<CFHTTPPARAM VALUE="#serializeJSON(stFields)#" TYPE="body">
```

Old answer:

*The [`serializeJSON` function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) serializes objects (structs, arrays, queries, components, simple values) and outputs the content as a JSON string.
Your `stFields` is already a JSON string, thus there's no need to serialize it (again):*

```
<CFHTTPPARAM VALUE="#stFields#" TYPE="body">
```

Comment: No Its is not Alex, Let me write how i am generating the `stFields`. I am editing my Question

Comment: if i remove single codes i get an error that passed json string to the api is not valid and this confused a lot as to what it is expecting

Comment: `'{"ONE":{"GROUP":"my group"}}'` is not valid JSON. `{"ONE":{"GROUP":"my group"}}` on the other hand, is. What exactly does the API expect?

Comment: this is what ia m sending from the POSTMAN API and it WORKS `http://prntscr.com/e72nxx`

Comment: @weqsd - Can you show us a cfdump of `stFields`? Because Alex's suggestion produces (and sends) that exact JSON string with CF11, assuming the original structure contains those keys, ie `<cfset stFields = {"zone": {"group":"my group"}}>`.

Comment: If you are using the example above, that structure will produce the correct json (though with upper case keys): `{"ZONE":{"GROUP":"my group"}} `.

Comment: yes, i am using same but why when i am pingging the server with cfhttp it is failing and gives me an error but when i try with poSTman, it works, what is raw in body when we check with POST and how we can pass it to the coldfusion, do i need to pass some UTF or encoding settings

Comment: Heck, this work i made all lowercase and it worked, but i am using coldfusion 11 and 2016, so is there any way i can lowercase these structure keys

Comment: did this: `lcase(serializeJson(stFields))` but that also converted the value, i want to keep the values as it is,

Comment: @weqsd - The old way was to use struct notation, instead of dot notation ie `structName["keyName"] = value`. If using the shorthand struct syntax, see the example in [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165514/passing-json-to-cfhttpparam#comment71499629_42165929).  Also see [the docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) for more options in CF11+.

Comment: What Leigh said, also be aware if the API you are using is strict on data types. ColdFusion will often try to convert numbers to a numeric JSON value. so for `foo.bar = '1234'`. Even though bar is a "string" CF will often if not always convert that to a number during the `serializeJSON` function and if the API enforces data types and is expecting a string, you'll have to handle that before you send it.